# Naming of namespace and classes

Tags: c#

In C# there are some problems with naming a namespace the same as a class that is included in that namespace.

In my project, I often have the same situation. I have a class that represents an abstraction of an external device (a USB relay for example). The code for such a device looks like this:

```
namespace Hardware.ExampleDeviceNamespace 
{
   class ExampleDevice
   {
      void executeCommand( DeviceCommand command ) {...}
      void checkConnection( DeviceConnection connection ) {...}
   }

   class DeviceCommand
   {
      ...
   }

   class DeviceConnection
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Now I am struggling with a proper name for the namespace ExampleDeviceNamespace and the class ExampleDevice, because I think adding the word "namespace" at the and of the actual name is not very nice. I am using a namespace for the ExampleDevice because I implemented a lot of helping classes like `DeviceCommand` and `DeviceConnection` and the namespace `Hardware` would get very messy without the folders. Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem? I am aware that of the fact, that there is no "right" solution for this question. But I would like to hear some ideas from other programmers.

If you have further questions to my problem, do not hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Why don't you do something like Namespace `ExampleDevice`, Classes `Main` `Command` `Connection`. Thus you have a standard structure for all your hardware.

Comment: How should **anyone** here give a **right** or **whrong** answer on such an opiniob-based question?

Comment: You need a grouping word.  Like Hardware.Example or Hardware.Devices.  Do strongly strive to make the connection and command device-independent.

Comment: If your namespace and the class inside should have the same names, then obviously something is wrong, because even if you can have the same name then it would be like `Hardware.ExampleDevice.ExampleDevice`, if there are several devices, then name like `Hardwar.Devices`, and if not then choose `Hardware.ExampleDevice` as namespace and it should contain only  `DeviceCommand` and `DeviceConnection` classes